# tablesorter: sort by unix seconds but display by specific date format

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have inconsistent dates pulled from the Pubmed website onto my webpage.  The dates can look like 2012 Jul, 2012 Jul 15, 2012 Jul 15-26, or 2012.  I am able to convert them to UNIX seconds in PHP and makes sorting easy, but obviously not friendly for us humans.  Essentially my HTML looks like:

```
<td>1341126000</td>
<td>1338534000</td>
<td>1322726400</td>
<td>1314860400</td>
```

etc...

Is there a way to use Tablesorter to sort by the unix seconds (digits), and somehow convert those UNIX seconds to a clean data format, such as mm/YYYY or YYYY-mm?

OR, is there a way to write a friendly Tablesorter parser that can sort a date format string like:

```
2012 Dec
2012 Mar
2011 Aug
2009 July
2009 Jan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  I was able to use the Tablesorter fork, which is Tablesorter on steroids!!!!  Its github page has the *perfect* example of what I needed.

http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use this table sorter:

https://github.com/briancray/taboosorter

Then you could use: `<td data-sortval="seconds_since_epoch">display_time</td>`.

It would automatically default to sorting by things in data-sortval if it exists.

Comment: Taboosorter worked in sorting the "data-sortval" tag, however, there is no dynamic sorting in real time like Tablesorter.  For example, if a user wants to view it in descending order or ascending order.  Tablesorter allows the user to click on the column header and it dynamically sorts all the rows in the table in real time.  Can taboosorter do this?

Comment: Clicking the header will resort the column.

Comment: What version of jQuery is required?  I did not mention this, but I am doing this in Drupal 7, and Drupal 7's jQuery version is 1.4.4.  Otherwise, clicking on the header in the <th> tag does not cause the columns to sort like Tablesorter.  I followed your demo.html on the github page, which looks very similar to Tablesorter, but it is not dynamically sorting.  All I can think of is that the jQuery version is too low since you are using 1.7.2.

Comment: Yea it uses .on, which was introduced in 1.7.